# What is the MERGED dataset in College Scorecard? Also, NULL data in DEBT_MDN

Tags: collegescorecard

I'm stepping in for someone who has worked with this data previously, so be gentle.

I don't understand all the different files in the CollegeScorecard_Raw_data set downloaded. Specifically, the MERGED files.
[image]

Some questions. I looked in the data dictionary, and on the website, and I can't find a straight answer explaining what the MERGED files are.

1. What are the MERGED files. What are they merged with?
2. DEBT_MDN data. Why does the `MERGED2020_21_PP.csv` have NULL data for `DEBT_MDN`? The DEBT_MDN was available in `MERGED2019_20_PP.csv` file.
3. **How** is the MERGED data different from the `Most-Recent-Cohorts-Institution` file? Does this file maintain values if the most recent data is NULL? Meaning, if in 2019-20, there was $XXX in a field, and the most recent year shows NULL, which value is maintained in the `Most-Recent-Cohorts-Institution` file?